# error: cannot find symbol variable abc_ic_menu_moreoverflow_mtrl_alpha

Tags: android, android-support-library

When migrating from version `23.4.0` to `24.x`, I've encountered this error:

`error: cannot find symbol variable abc_ic_menu_moreoverflow_mtrl_alpha`

What is causing that? Is there any way

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This resource has been renamed. Simply changing `abc_ic_menu_moreoverflow_mtrl_alpha` to `abc_ic_menu_overflow_material` solves the issue.

[Source](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v7/appcompat/res/drawable/abc_ic_menu_overflow_material.xml)